# Decode a GStreamer jpeg stream with c# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tcp, jpeg, gstreamer

I have a stream that I planned to encode with GStreamer and send it over TCP, then decode them in Unity.

This is my GStreamer pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! queue ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! jpegenc ! multipartmux ! tcpserversink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
```

I have problem with getting the **Byte array size** for each jpeg frame.
In order to properly read each frame, I need to first get the size of each frame, and create a byte array of that size.
`var read = serverStream.Read(imageBytes, 0, **size**);`

If I take `multipartmux` out from the pipeline, it seems like a long sequence of data, and it stops after the first frame is received (`serverStream.DataAvailable` = FALSE)

If I keep `multipartmux` in the pipeline, I will first receive a Byte array that it's length is roughly 70~80, then I get the sequence of data.
Looking like this:

```
 { 45, 45, 84, 104, 105, 115, 82, 97, 110, 100, 111, 109, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 13, 10, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 45, 84, 121, 112, 101, 58, 32, 105, 109, 97, 103, 101, 47, 106, 112, 101, 103, 13, 10, 67, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 45, 76, 101, 110, 103, 116, 104, 58, 32, 51, 54, 55, 49, 52, 13, 10, 13, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,}
```

But I don't understand the meaning of that Byte array... is the Byte array size somehow described in that?

If anyone can help me with the interpretation of these data, or give me some insight about GStreamer jpeg encoding and how to decode them, it would be great. Thank you!

```
 private void readFrameByteArray(int size) {
            bool disconnected = false;
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("- image size: " + size);
            NetworkStream serverStream = client.GetStream();
            serverStream.ReadTimeout = 10;
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("ckp 1");
            byte[] imageBytes = new byte[size];
            var total = 0;
            var sb = new StringBuilder("imageBytes[] { ");
            do
            {
            //serverStream.ReadTimeout = 100;
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("ckp2: "+ serverStream.DataAvailable);
                if (!serverStream.DataAvailable)return;
            
            var read = serverStream.Read(imageBytes, total, size);
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("ckp3");
            if (read == 0)
                {
                    disconnected = true;
                    break;
                }
                total += read;
                //UnityEngine.Debug.Log("- read: " + read);
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("- FrameByteArray total: " + total);
                foreach (var b in imageBytes)
                {
                    sb.Append(b + ", ");
                    //if (b == 0) break;
                }
                sb.Append("}");
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log(sb.ToString());
            } while (serverStream.DataAvailable);
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("!serverStream.DataAvailable");
            

            bool readyToReadAgain = false;

            //Display Image
            if (!disconnected) {
                //Display Image on the main Thread
                Loom.QueueOnMainThread(() => {
                    loadReceivedImage(imageBytes);
                    readyToReadAgain = true;
                });
            }

            //Wait until old Image is displayed
            while (!readyToReadAgain) {
                UnityEngine.Debug.Log("!readyToReadAgain");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that is looking for a solution, this is how I eventually got by:

```
 public class _TextureReceiver : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public int port = 5000;
        public string IP = "127.0.0.1";
        TcpClient client;
        private NetworkStream serverStream;

        [HideInInspector]
        public Texture2D texture;

        private bool stop = false;

        [Header("Must be the same in sender and receiver")]
        public int messageByteLength = 24;

        public int maxFrameSize = 40000;

        int try_count = 1;

        // Use this for initialization
        void Start()
        {
            //UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Start!");
            Application.runInBackground = true;

            client = new TcpClient();

            //Connect to server from another Thread
            Loom.RunAsync(() =>
            {
                TCP_Connect();

            });
        }

        public void enStop()
        {
            stop = true;

            if (client != null)
            {
                client.Close();
            }

            if (serverStream != null)
            {
                serverStream.Close();
            }
            return;
        }

        public void TCP_Connect()
        {
            client = new TcpClient();
            IAsyncResult result = client.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Parse(IP), port, null, null);
            result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000, true);
            if (!client.Connected)
            {
                if (try_count > 0)
                {
                   // UnityEngine.Debug.LogError("Ethernet Connection Error, Retry");
                    try_count++;
                    client.Close();
                    TCP_Connect();
                }
                else
                {
                    client.Close();
                    //UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Missing Connection");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //UnityEngine.Debug.Log("V");
                imageReceiver();
            }
        }
        public void imageReceiver()
        {
            //While loop in another Thread is fine so we don't block main Unity Thread
            Loom.RunAsync(() =>
            {
                while (!stop)
                {
                    readFrameByteArray(maxFrameSize);
                }
            });
        }


        private void readFrameByteArray(int size)
        {
            bool disconnected = false;
            serverStream = client.GetStream();

            byte[] imageBytes = new byte[size];
            var total = 0;

            //UnityEngine.Debug.Log("serverStream.DataAvailable: "+ serverStream.DataAvailable);
            if (!serverStream.DataAvailable) return;

            var read = serverStream.Read(imageBytes, total, size);
            if (read == 0)
            {
                disconnected = true;
                //break;
            }
            total += read;
            if (read == maxFrameSize) maxFrameSize += 5000;
            //UnityEngine.Debug.Log("[V]read: " + read);


            bool readyToReadAgain = false;

            //Display Image
            if (!disconnected)
            {
                //Display Image on the main Thread
                Loom.QueueOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    loadReceivedImage(imageBytes);
                    readyToReadAgain = true;

                });
            }

            //Wait until old Image is displayed
            while (!readyToReadAgain)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
            }

            return;
        }


        void loadReceivedImage(byte[] receivedImageBytes)
        {
            //UnityEngine.Debug.Log("* load Received Image *");

            if (texture)
            {
                if (receivedImageBytes[0] == 255 && receivedImageBytes[1] == 216 && receivedImageBytes[2] == 255 && receivedImageBytes[3] == 224 && receivedImageBytes[4] == 0 && receivedImageBytes[5] == 16 && receivedImageBytes[6] == 74 && receivedImageBytes[7] == 70 && receivedImageBytes[8] == 73 && receivedImageBytes[9] == 70)
                {
                    //UnityEngine.Debug.Log("* texture *");
                    texture.LoadImage(receivedImageBytes);
                }

            }
        }

        public void SetTargetTexture(Texture2D t)
        {
            texture = t;
        }

        public void OnApplicationQuit()
        {
            enStop();
        }




    }
```